# How is List<T>.IndexOf() implemented in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list

I was thinking about the performance of calling `List<T>.Indexof(item)`. I am not sure if it will be a O(n) performance for a sequential algorithm or O(log(n)) performance for a binary tree??

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using Reflector for .NET we can see:

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
{
    return Array.IndexOf<T>(this._items, item, 0, this._size);
}

public static int IndexOf<T>(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.IndexOf(array, value, startIndex, count);
}

internal virtual int IndexOf(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    int num = startIndex + count;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (this.Equals(array[i], value))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Don't ever look at the code when there's detailed documentation. Sometimes the code is just an implementation detail, and there are no guarantees.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: MSDN articles sometimes are very good, sometime are awful. So if you have a question about implementation of specific method, I think the best way - go and see how does it really implemented.

Comment: When the code and comments disagree, both are probably wrong.

Comment: @abatishchev do you have reflector for Add() method ?

Answer (score 35):

It's `O(n)` according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx).

> This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

Answer (score 15):

`List<T>` is backed by a flat array, so `list.IndexOf(item)` is O(n).

Answer (score 7):

`List<T>.IndexOf` is O(n) which is in fact optimal for an unordered set of n elements.

`List<T>.BinarySearch` is O(log n) but only works correctly if the List is sorted.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a faster performer, consider `HashSet<T>`. It's a speed vs. memory tradeoff, but it is worth it if you value the former over the latter.

(It's not exactly the same as a `List<T>`, it behaves like a single column dictionary, but for instances where you are going to have a unique list, it's one way to do it.)

Answer (score 4):

My late answer but I think it worth mentioning that nowadays you can directly access to the MS sources: 
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

No more need for reflection since the .NET BCL code is now available online.

> Implements a variable-size List that uses an array of objects to store
>   the elements. A List has a capacity, which is the allocated length of
>   the internal array. As elements are added to a List, the capacity of
>   the List is automatically increased as required by reallocating the
>   internal array.

As implemented as an array and performing a ***linear search***, you can easily deduce that the algorithmic complexity of the `IndexOf` method is **O(n)**.

As mentioned by others the information are publicly available on the msdn: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx

> This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an
>   O(n) operation, where n is Count.

Again, you can check out the sources and end up seing that the static helper method `IndexOf` of the Array class is actually called behind the scenes:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs

If the list / array is already sorted beforehand you can then rather use a binary search:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx

> This method is an O(log n) operation, where n is the number of
>   elements in the range.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for that. I don't care what people say, sometimes you just gotta look at the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Behind the scenes a regular `array`is used, infact the `IndexOf` method simply calls `Array.IndexOf`. Since arrays don't sort elements, performance is O(n).